# Regex group string where the delimiter can be used twice (.net regex)

Tags: .net, regex, excel, openxml, regex-group

I am writing a parser for excel that can update values in the document. I am currently parsing the header/footer part of the spreadsheet document format. The format of a header/footer in excel is stored as plain text, delimited by:

- `&L`
- `&C`
- `&R`

So your header / footer might look like this in the xml:

`&LTodaysDate&CDocumentTitle&RAuthors Name`

If you have only a left and right header your xml string would look like:

`&LTodaysDate&RAuthors Name`

I have tried to create a pattern that can detect each of thee groups and parse out the component (ie `&L`,`&C`,`&R`) along with any text that occurs after that tag.

**The regex string is this**: `(&.{1})([A-Za-z\d_ ]*)` ([Link to example](https://regexr.com/4b199))

However I have a fringe case problem that will mean I can't properly parse excel header that contain ampersands.

In an excel header for your document to have an ampersand in the title (this is in plain text) you must type `&&`. So the xml of a header with an ampersands might look like:

`&RPork && Beans` (which would display "Pork & Beans" in the spreadsheet).

My regex is not able to cope with the premature ampersand. In the first group (`(&.{1})`) I ask for anything that has an ampersand and the character that follows it (ie an L/C/R). How can I tell this group to not include when there are 2 ampersands. My regex skills are pretty novice, I can describe what I want at a higher level:

I want to split the string wherever I see &L/&C/&R and capture all text after this, up to another &L/&C/&R delimiter (excluding new line spaces etc). I can best describe this in C# linq below.

`(&.{1}.Where(c => c != '&'))([A-Za-z\d_ ]*)`

For the string "&RPork && Beans"

my regex captures 2 matches each with 2 groups:

*match 1*
group 1: "&R"
group 2: "Pork "

*match 2*
group 1: "&&"
group 2: " Beans"

and I'd want it to match once:
group 1: "&R"
group 2: "Pork && Beans"

Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, but can't you use `Regex.Split(s, "(&[LRC])")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew to be honest i was doing all of my regex's online on regexr and totally glossed over the fact .net could do that >.>

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was just putting it into my code and running some tests to verify that the solution worked. I've marked your answer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
var result = Regex.Split(s, "(&[LRC])").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%26%5BLRC%5D%29&i=%26RPork%20%26%26%20Beans%26CDocument%20Title). The `(&[LRC])` will match `&` and a `L`, `R` or `C` letter after it, this value will be extracted into the resulting array due to the capturing parentheses.

[image]

[Another usage example](https://ideone.com/WR4xXg):

```
var s = "&RPork && Beans&CDocument Title";
var result = Regex.Split(s, "(&[LRC])")
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
        .ToList();
var data = result.Where((c,i) => i % 2 == 0).Zip(result.Where((c,i) => i % 2 != 0),
        (delimiter, value) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(delimiter, value));
foreach (var kvp in data)
    Console.WriteLine("Delimiter: {0}\nValue: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```

Output:

```
Delimiter: &R
Value: Pork && Beans
Delimiter: &C
Value: Document Title
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I've implemented this approach in my code 

Answer (score 1):

upon my understanding to the case i have written regex that matches what you need ([Link to example](https://regexr.com/4b1pg) 
)

and this is the expression :

(&(?=[RCL])[RCL]{1})([A-Za-z\d_ ]*(&(?![RCL]))*[A-Za-z\d_ ]*)*